# Running a Bash script in multiple directories in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

I would like to run some commands within a number of directories as the following code outlines:

```
    for d in dir*;
    do
        touch $d/file.txt
    done
```

But while the above code works for directories without spaces in their names, it does not if they do have spaces like: Directory 1 instead of Directory1, each word is treated as a different directory. Any way to overcome this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's ask [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net)!

```
In myscript line 3:
    touch $d/file.txt
          ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

Ok, let's do that:

```
for d in dir*;
do
    touch "$d"/file.txt
done
```

and now it works.

Comment: Perfect, thanks (and thanks for pointing me to shellcheck, never knew about this).